# Can I use BrewPi and Fermwrap without a chamber?

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature, temperature, temperature-control, fermwrap

I've been looking into fermentation temperature control and came across BrewPi. Even though I live in Southern California, I'd like to be able to keep some brews at optimal temperature -- the house does get somewhat cold during the winter. Relatively, at least ;)

Can I use the [this BrewPi setup](http://diybrewpi.wikia.com/wiki/DIYBrewPi_Wikia) with a Fermwrap ***without*** a fermentation chamber? I can probably put it into a small room where heat loss will be minimal. I already have a kegerator, so having another similar contraption isn't feasible right now in terms of space or appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can use a BrewPi without any chamber, be be aware it will be much more difficult to maintain proper temps if your environment has wide swings in temperature throughout the day.

Also, it will be more expensive to maintain temperature.  Isolating your fermenter from the outside environment allows the Fermwrap to work much less as the chamber itself will lend a hand in keeping the fermenter at whatever temp you choose.

Even something as simple as a box made of rigid insulation will make it MUCH easier on your setup and your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Suer you can do this.  You don't need a chamber but you do need some insulation.  Just wrap the fermentor in a couple heavy towels or an old blanket or something.  I live in the northeast. I would lager in the winter time but putting my fermentor in a plastic bin lined with old beach towels.  Then I'd cover the thing with an old towel.  The heater did fine keep the beer at the right temp.  No need for a fancy chamber.

Comment: I assume risk of fire is low when using blankets/towels, right?